# How to store checkbox statuses after I exit app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have tab layout (3 fragments) with recyclerview and checkboxes for every fragment. I set up onClickListener, but after I exit my app, checkbox statuses are reseted. I tried some solutions I found online some solutions (about shared preferences) but neither work for me. Maybe I implement it wrong. Can you help me ?

Also if need, I can share with you my Fragment file.

recyclerview java:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context mContext;
    List<RecTab1> mData;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<RecTab1> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v ;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_tab1,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_subName.setText(mData.get(position).getSubName());
        holder.cb_checkbox.setChecked(mData.get(position).getSelected());
        holder.cb_checkbox.setTag(position);
        holder.cb_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer pos = (Integer) holder.cb_checkbox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mData.get(pos).getName() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mData.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                    mData.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    mData.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView tv_name;
        private TextView tv_subName;
        private CheckBox cb_checkbox;

        public MyViewHolder (View itemView){
            super (itemView);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Item1Name);
            tv_subName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Item1SubName);
            cb_checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CheckboxID);
        }
    }
}
```

item java:

```
public class RecTab1 {
    private String Name;
    private String SubName;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public RecTab1(){
    }
    public RecTab1 (String name, String subName){
        Name = name;
        SubName = subName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public String getSubName() {
        return SubName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public void setSubName(String subName) {
        SubName = subName;
    }
    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: See this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I found this before, but I don't know how to implement in my app because I have Fragment and Recyclerview adapter and I don't know where should I place code.

Comment: Since, you want to customize views that are inside the `viewholder`, you need to put this code inside the `adapter` class. Listen for `checkChanged` event of those `checkbox` inside your `ViewHolder` class and set current `checked` info using `SharedPreferences`. Then retrieve it later inside `onBindViewHolder()` method.

Comment: I can't handle it. I am trying all day. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 kinds of persistence:

- Temporary persistence (Scope: can be only used inside `Activity`/`Fragment`)
- Long-term persistence (Scope: goes beyond the lifecycle of `Activity`/`Fragment`)

I think, you implemented **first technique** by creating `Rect1` object somewhere(I assumed you did not save them in the database as I did not see those lines of code) and later trying to access the values when needed elsewhere. But, those variables will be destroyed and recreated later on **destroying and recreating** of the fragment when you would switch between `tabs` in your `TabLayout`.
**What you need is the second one.**
There are many versions of this kind of persistence as :
 - SharedPreferences
 - Sqlite Database
 - Online Database such as Firebase
For eg: In your case, if you have few numbers of `tabs` which again has few numbers of information to persist then, you can use `SharedPreferences`. If there is larger number of `tabs` and in turn larger number of information to persist then, using Sqlite Database is better. [See this link about using Room to save data in Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Now using `SharedPreferences`, you can save the `checked` state of the `CheckBox` into the preference file in the `onCheckChangedListener` method as:

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_tab1, parent, false);
    Checkbox cb_checkbox = v.findViewById(R.id.CheckboxID);
    cb_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.example.yourapp.SAVED_STATE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)  
                        .edit()  
                        .putBoolean("cb_checkbox", isChecked)
                        .apply();
                }
            });
```

I set the `onCheckChangedListener` in the `onCreateViewHolder` because `mContext` was available. You could have also done in inside the `MyViewHolder` class passing the `Context` object in the constructor of `MyViewHolder`.It is **NOT recommended** to set listener in `onBindViewHolder()` because it is called multiple times during binding so, there would be recurrent setting of listener even for those `cb_checkbox` in the `MyViewHolder` object whose listeners are already set.

Now, to retrieve the `checked` state of the `cb_checkbox`, we will see in our `SharedPreferences` to find information if it is saved previously as :

```
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                // your other binding code
                // code for binding previous state of the checkbox if is saved otherwise false as a default 
                boolean checkedState = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.example.yourapp.SAVED_STATE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .getBoolean("cb_checkbox", false);
                holder.cb_checkbox.setChecked(checkedState);
            }
```